# Discord Custom Activity Attribute Error, emoji object doesn't have attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

My code:

```
emoji = client.get_emoji(id=773100346749878293)
activity = discord.CustomActivity(name="DMs", type=discord.ActivityType.watching, emoji=emoji.)
await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=activity)
```

So when I run it, an error throw out:

```
animated=data.get('animated', False),
AttributeError: 'Emoji' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Entire Function:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def change_presence():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    emoji = client.get_emoji(773100346749878293)
    activity = discord.CustomActivity(name="DMs", type=discord.ActivityType.watching, emoji=emoji)
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=activity)
```

Any ways to fix this or this is an error from the Library?

Comment: That's not how you retrieve an emoji, use client.get_emoji(773100346749878293)

Comment: id is the arg needed, so it doesn't matter. And your method also cannot fix this problem.

Comment: Please show us the full function and what is `animated=data.get('animated', False),` so we can understand what is happening in that call.

Comment: this is the function in Discord Library

Comment: edited the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this seems to be because `discord.py` is not expecting an `emoji` object in the initialization of a `CustomActivity`, instead it is expecting you to pass a dictionary containing that emoji. You will need to pass a dictionary to not get that error.

[Source code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/e473f3c775b26a4bb54b18eb6240757306f4f5c1/discord/activity.py#L696)

On another topic, a bot is not allowed to have a CustomActivity, this is something internally managed by Discord so we cannot do anything about it. Only users can set custom activities, so if your code belongs to a bot it will not work despite solving the error.

[Reference issue](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2400)